# I want to count repeat word in String variable

Tags: php

I want to count repeat word and display

```
$string = "abc, abcd, aec, abc, aaa, ccc, aec, abc, efg, abc, aaa, aec, cde";

$words = explode(',',$string);
foreach($words as $key) {
   ????
}
```

How to display
abc = 4
aec = 3
..

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = "abc, abcd, aec, abc, aaa, ccc, aec, abc, efg, abc, aaa, aec, cde";

$words = explode(',',$string);
$results = array();

foreach($words as $key) {
    if(!isset($results[$key])){
        $results[$key] = 0;
    }

    $results[$key]++;
}

var_dump($results);
```

Seams to work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) rather than a `foreach` loop:

```
$string = "abc, abcd, aec, abc, aaa, ccc, aec, abc, efg, abc, aaa, aec, cde";

$array = explode(',', $string);

//Trim it up first.
$array = array_map(function($item){
    return trim($item);
}, $array);

$array = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item){
    if(isset($carry[$item])) {
        $carry[$item]++;
    } else {
        $carry[$item] = 1;
    }

    return $carry;
});

var_dump($array);
```

[Try it!](https://3v4l.org/YaPsk)

Comment: Nice example of a big data approach!